# How to avoid Multiple Definitions in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a big C++ Project, in which I try to implement a debug function which needs classes from other libraries. Unfortunately these classes share the same name and namespaces with classes called inside the project. I tried to use a static library to avoid multiple definitions, but of course the compiler complains about that issue. So my question: 
It is possible to create that library for the function without that the compiler knows about the called classes inside the function?

I don't know, like a "protected function" or like putting all the code from the libraries inside the function code..

*Edit: I'm using the g++ compiler.*

*Max, I know but so far I see no other way.*

Schematic, the problem is.

Project:

```
#include a.h // (old one)
#include a2.h

return a->something();
return a2->something(); //debug function
```

debug function a2:

```
#include a.h // (new one!!)

return a->something(); // (new one!)
```

Compiling Process looks so far:

```
g++ project -la -la2
```

That is a very simplified draft. But that's it actually.

Comment: Show us a sample of something that is defined multiple times.

Comment: C++ provides a way to avoid accidental name clashes like what you're running into:  namespaces.  However, it sounds like the debug library code uses the same class names in the same namespaces to do different things.  It may be possible to make this happen, but it will confuse developers (no I don't want *that* `Foo::Bar`, I want the other one!").  It's perfectly reasonable to have the debugging library use the other library -- although then you have to watch for circular dependencies -- and I would suspect that's a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can create a wrapper library which internally links to that outside library and exports its definitions under a different name or namespace.

Answer (score 1):

try enclosing the #includes for the declarations of the classes that you are using in your debug function in a namspace, but don't use an using clause for that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few techniques that may help you, but that depends on what the "debug version" of the library does.

First, it's not unheard of to have `#ifdef` blocks inside functions that do additional checking depending on whether the program was built in debug mode.  The C `assert` macro behaves this way.

Second, it's possible that the "debug version" does nothing more than log messages.  It's easy enough to include the logging code in both debug and release versions, and make the decision to actually log based on some kind of "priority" parameter for each log message.

Third, you may consider using an event-based design where functions can, optionally, take objects as parameters that have certain methods, and then if interesting things happen and the function was passed an event object, the function can call those methods.

Finally, if you're actually interested in what happens at a lower level than the library you're working on, you can simply link to debug versions of those lower level libraries.  This is a case of the first option mentioned above, applied to a different library than the one you're actually working on.  Microsoft's [runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982%28v=vs.110%29) libraries do this, as do Google's [perftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) and many "debugging `malloc`" libraries.